# display the custom post type post in page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named "audio". To display all the posts in a page I wrote the code below, but it does not work.

```
          <?php
    $post_type = "audioes";//post type names
    echo "djnbfj";
     $post_type->the_post();
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => $post_type,
     'orderby' => 'post_date',
     'order' => 'DESC',
     'showposts' => 1,
    ));

    // The Loop
    ?>

    <?php
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="issue-content">
          <?php get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs', 'page'); ?>
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail();}
           get_template_part('loop-audio', 'page');
          ?>
     </div><!--issue-content-->
    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div> <!-- end #left_area -->
```

How can i got the posts type i want the custom one written above.

Answer (score 0):

Is the post type called "audio" or "audioes"? Your $post_type variable is set to "audioes".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `get_template_part` lines or the `echo` line is doing, but the below code should display your post type.  You also have the post type name as "audioes" in your code, but you state that the name is "audio".  Try the code below, but if the post type is named "audioes" then you'll need to change that in my code below.  You can wrap additional divs, spans, or other HTML tags around `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` and `<?php the_content(); ?>` to give them CSS styles is you wish to.

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'audio', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC')); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="issue-content">

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

</div> 

<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```